# Help interpreting open text file

Tags: python

I have an existing Arcpy script written by others that I need help interpreting. The script reads records from a feature class and loops through and writes them to a log file.  Here is the section I need help with:  Hope this conforms.

```
if r_count <= 0:
        print str(r_count) + " No IDs Found"

        # Open a log text file for reading
        ef = open(ERRORFILEname2, 'rb')
        # Create a text/plain message
        msg_body = MIMEText(ef.read())
        ef.close()
```

Question: what does the 'rb' represent in the open statement?  Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to open the file in binary mode... read the python help section here, specifically section 7.2... http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: More specifically, open the file in Read Only mode (as opposed to Write) & Binary mode.